# Regular expression to read n number of count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I am having one html document which have lots of PO number .

I am trying to retrieve. I am not good with regular expression. I am able to find with first no with by position. but i need all of them. how to do that.

my Html file look like

```
<html>
 <head></head>
<body>
<br>
Invoice Number : [12346456] PO Number : [6464645]

<hr>
Invoice Number : [90156460] PO Number : [6416462]

<hr>
Invoice Number : [90868741] PO Number : [1613464]

</body>
</html>
```

My code

```
po_count = page.css('body').text.scan(/\d+/)[1].to_i
```

In which i am getting first `PO Number 6464645`
I need all PO Number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very lean but should work:

```
po_numbers = []
page.css('body').text.scan(/Invoice Number : \[\d+\] PO Number : \[(\d+)\]/) do
  po_numbers << $1.to_i
end
```

Comment: `text.scan(/(?<=PO Number : \[)\d+/).map &:to_i` ⇒ `[6464645, 6416462, 1613464]`

Answer (score 1):

```
po_count = page.css('body').text.scan(/\d+/)
```

will generate array of matches

```
po_count = ["12346456", "6464645", "90156460", "6416462", "90868741", "1613464"]

po_count = po_count.map{|e| e.to_i}
```

will make

```
po_count = [12346456, 6464645, 90156460, 6416462, 90868741, 1613464]
```

Comment: Thanks Nermin I am having lots of no on page . In which i need only PO Number.